# How to access in this array of objects

Tags: powershell

I have this part of code -

```
$result = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
    Select-Object DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate, UnistallString | 
    Where-Object InstallDate -GT 20180201 | 
    Where-Object UnistallDate -NotMatch " " | 
    Sort-Object -Property InstallDate -Descending | 
    Format-Table –AutoSize
$result
```

With the result of this command I get an array of objects, but if I try to access in it I get no result.

Example:
  `$result.UnisistallString`. How can I access in it to get only the attributes of that parameter? Because with that then I need to print on video the name of the program and the unistall path.

Comment: `| Format-Table –AutoSize` - remove this part.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `Format-Table` cmdlet if you need to access the data in your code later. Also you have a **typo** in your example and the select statement. This should work:

```
$result = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
    Select-Object DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate, UninstallString | 
    Where-Object InstallDate -GT 20180201 |  
    Sort-Object -Property InstallDate -Descending
```

Now Access it using:

```
$result.UninstallString
```

Comment: Still cant access to that, if i run the script i get 0 result on display

Comment: I'll try to explain, after the get-itemproperty i should access to the array to print only the name of the program and his unistall path. But if i cant access to the array i cant print that

Comment: I also tried to use the get-wmiobject for the same purpose, but after the query i cant access to any property of the result

Comment: As I wrote, please try my code again, I had to fix another typo that you made in the select statement.

Comment: I already tryed it twice, still cant get any results from the print

Comment: Did you checked whether `$result` contains any data? I tested the snipet, It does return the strings for me.

Comment: As i wrote, i tryed on another code: $result = get-wmiobject -class ‘Win32_Product’ -computer Computer
But even in this one i cant access to it if i call the $result.Name

Comment: If i only call the $result it gives me the parameters, but i dont need all of them. From the result i get, i need to extract the path and the name to print in video those parameters

Comment: `Where-Object UnistallDate -NotMatch " "` is not doing any good here since there is no `UnistallDate` property even if it was spelled correctly....

Comment: @Matt you are right. Will also remove this. The example had multiple errors. However, I get the uninstall string with the script

Comment: Even after taking off the unistalldate i dont have any result if i do the $result.UnistallString. Could it be powergui the problem? Because i cant use powershell ise to work with scripts